# WPF ObservableCollection Insert at index and NotifyOnTargetUpdated

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, eventtrigger

**What**

A DataGrid is bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.

Every 2 seconds, an item get modified/added alternatively.

The modified/added item datagrid row get highlighted for 1 second.

**Problem**

The item added must be inserted at a given index, not necessarily at the end of the ObservableCollection. This is achieved by using `Insert(int index, ListItemVM item)`.

**Bug**

The item is added at index 1, in 2nd position. The UI gets updated accordingly and highlights the new item **BUT ALSO INCORRECTLY HIGHLIGHTS THE LAST ITEM**. I would really like to get rid of the unwanted behavior and I can't figure how.

The code is runnable:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="None" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Blue" To="Transparent" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtTheData" Text="{Binding TheData, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Background="Transparent" />
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new MainWindowVM();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        Random random = new Random();

        public ObservableCollection<ListItemVM> MyList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListItemVM>
            {
                new ListItemVM(1, "Data1"),
                new ListItemVM(2, "Data2"),
                new ListItemVM(3, "Data3"),
            };

        bool mustAdd;
        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
            timer.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                mustAdd = !mustAdd;
                if (mustAdd == false)
                {
                    // Emulate Update existing
                    var nextData = new string(Enumerable.Repeat("ABCDEFG", 10).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
                    MyList[1].SetNewData(nextData);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Emulate Add new
                    var newItem = new ListItemVM(99, "old");
                    MyList.Insert(1, newItem);
                    // Notify the UI of the change
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyList)));
                    newItem.SetNewData("NEW");
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Item ViewModel**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class ListItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TheData { get; set; }

        public ListItemVM(int id, string theData)
        {
            Id = id;
            TheData = theData;
        }

        internal void SetNewData(string nextData)
        {
            // Change data
            TheData = nextData;
            // Notify the UI of the change
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TheData)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424994/wpf-datagrid-highlight-new-rows-when-inserted-into-datagrid

Comment: Just disable item container recycling (virtualization).

Comment: You're not always inserting you're also updating an existing item. Collections in c# are indexed using zero base. Hence the first is index 0, second 1. An observablecollection implements inotifycollectionchanged. If you set an item in the collection to another object or even itself, it raises change for that whole item. If you insert. it raises for that new item. You could handle that event in the view and use it to start an animation.

Comment: @andy The update is working fine and is in the example for the sake of completion. The bug is about adding an item

Comment: @ibiza: So why are you handling `Binding.TargetUpdated`instead of using an attached behaviour as I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049905/wpf-datagrid-highlight-row-on-data-change)? This event will be raised for the last row as well.

Comment: Thanks @Aakanksha and BionicCode ! Disabling Virtualization did the trick, I am so happy! :D

Comment: @ibiza: You know the reason why virtualization is enabled by default, right? Performance.

Answer (score 0):

How about, instead of starting the highlight animation on `Binding.TargetUpdated`, you set a property on the ViewModel, like

```
private bool _shouldHighlight = false;
public bool ShouldHighlight
{
    get => _shouldHighlight;
    set
    {
        _shouldHighlight = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ShouldHighlight)));
    }
}
```

When you add the item to the collection, first of all set for all elements ShouldHighlight = false, then add the element with ShouldHighlight = true.

In the view, instead of

```
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        ...
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
```

you could use a DataTrigger with Binding set to ShouldHighlight and Value = True. Or subscribe to DataContext's PropertyChanged event (in the xaml.cs Loaded event) and start the highlight animation when PropertyChanged's args show a change in the ShouldHighlight to true:

```
Loaded += delegate
{
    if (DataContext is ListItemVM viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += delegate (object o, PropertyChangedArgs args)
        {
             if (args.PropertyName == nameof(viewModel.ShouldHighlight) && viewModel.ShouldHighlight)
                 // Starts the animation //
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just guessing, let me know if it works :)