# selecting all wpf datagrid checkboxes only selects items in view

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have the following method to select all the checkboxes within my datagrid:

```
   private void CheckboxSelectAll(int column)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < twn; i++)
        {

            var row = (DataGridRow)dGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

            if (row == null) continue;
            var chk = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)dGrid.Columns[column].GetCellContent(row);
            chk.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

This only works so long as all the columns are in view. If, for example, the amount of checkboxes exceeds the height of the datagrid, it will not select those. I will have to scroll down, expose them to the view, and then reinvoke my method to finally select the remaining checkboxes.

What am I missing? These checkboxes are already databound.

If I change the height of the datagrid to expose more checkboxes, this allows me to select more. This is only a workaround and I would like to understand why and what about my code makes the checkboxes being exposed to the view important.

Comment: In your loop, what is twn?

Comment: a double which is also equal to the amount of rows that exist.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found here:

[WPF Toolkit DataGrid Checkbox Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497617/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-checkbox-issues?rq=1)

The solution is to disable RowVirtualization

```
EnableRowVirtualization="False"
```

Comment: You might get performance issue if you have large number of rows, if you disable the virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing? These checkboxes are already databound.

If the `CheckBox`es are databound you should set the value of the *source* property that the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` is bound to.

For example, if your `CheckBox` is defined something like this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
```

...you should set the `Checked` property:

```
foreach(var item in dGrid.Items.OfType<YourClass>())
{
    item.Checked = true;
}
```

Make sure that the class where the `Checked` property is defined implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx.

This is a way better solution that disabling the built-in virtualization as the latter may affect the performance negatively.